Java wrong ScreenSize() in Swing
I changed from Java 1.8 to 23.0.1.
I am using JDK zulu23.30.13-ca-fx-jdk23.0.1-win_x64
Now - only if I'm using Java23 -
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() returns a wrong screensize 1536 x 864
instead of 1920 x 1080.
Can anyone tell me the reason?
Thank you
Andi

This is a JDK bug fix and (on Windows at least) relates to the font scaling size. See duplicate. You can determine scaled or unscaled screen resolution if following answer here

Rarely do applications need to call getScreenSize().  If you want your window to fill the screen, maximize it.  (If the application is a game, you may want to use setFullScreenWindow instead.)  If you want to center a window, use setLocationRelativeTo(null).
